# Creating component instance inside a function in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

i have a component that creates graphs and has an option to download them. i want to add the ability to download all available graphs on one click.

```
const CytoscapejsComponentself = ({
  graphData,
  clickedVector,
}: IGraphProps): IGraphReturn => {

    const btnSVGClick = () => {
          // Handle SVG click logic
    };

    const jsxVal = (<div>{/* some layout */}</div>)

    return { btnSVGClick, jsx: jsxVal };
};

export default CytoscapejsComponentself;
```

the idea was to create a function that creates instances of each graph component and activates the download function inside them, but i cant get the component instance creation to work.

my initial try was to first to test if i can get a single component created in a new function and downloaded so i did this:

```
const downloadAll = (type: "svg") => {

    const myComponent = CytoscapejsComponentself({graphData, clickedVector});
    
     if (type === "svg") {
       myComponent.btnSVGClick();
    }
};
```

the problem here was on the call for `CytoscapejsComponentself({graphData, clickedVector})`, i got a critical react hook call error.
outside of the function(in a different component to not create an infinite loop) i didn't get a critical error but it also has some bugs. it looks something like this:

```js
const Result: FC = () => {
/* rest of component */
  const myGraph = CytoscapejsComponentself({graphData, clickedVector});

  return (<div> {myGraph.jsx /* + some layout */} </div>
}
export default Result;
```

this should be a simpler version so i did most of my debugging on this call.

so when calling it outside of a function(but inside the function component `Result`) it didn't produce a critical error but it didnt work fully as well. when calling for a different graph it looks like there is no re-render of the component because the resulting graph is a union graph(contains all nodes and links from both graphs)

to solve this i tried putting the return value in a state: `const [myGraph, setMyGraph] = setState(CytoscapejsComponentself({graphData, clickedVector}))` but here it looks like the component is "frozen" in the initial state because i just get the default isLoading div to display when the graph is still being processed.

i also tried to put it in a react function instead

```js
function rederGraph(){
  const myGraph = CytoscapejsComponentself({graphData, clickedVector, thresholds});
    return myGraph.jsx;
}
```

but that also didn't help and caused a different critical error: "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render".

I think I'm just doing something wrong and there's just a different way to achieve the same result(maybe write it as a class instead of function? i would rather find another solution because this component has 1000+ lines. either way I'm out of ideas to try and would love some help.

Comment: Do you use any react hook, please show it.

Comment: @LinDu not really. i tried using useState and useEffect in different ways to fix this bug but i doubt i did it correctly because it didn't improve the situation, just caused bigger bugs. the main approach was to wrap the functions/return values. for example `const [myComp, setMyComp] = useState(CytoscapejsComponentself({graphData, clickedVector}))`